# Passing printf() as a parameter

Tags: c, string, gcc, printf

I'm trying to make a simple BST ADT, and I'm having some problems since I'm still new to C.

It compiles, but with warnings and a 'note', if I run the progam it only prints one element, the root node ( i want it to print all elements inorder).

I only provided code snippets that I thought was necessary, if you want all the code just ask.

bst.c - BST traversal method

```
41    void bst_inorder(bst b, void f(char *str)) {
42       if (b->key == NULL) {
43          return;
44       }
45       bst_inorder(b->left, f);
46       f(b->key);
47       bst_inorder(b->right, f);
48    }
```

TEST.c

```
14    bst_inorder(my_bst, printf);
```

bst.h

```
10    extern void bst_inorder(bst b, void f(char *str));
```

I'm compiling it like this

```
gcc -O2 -W -Wall -ansi -pedantic *.c -o TEST
```

and I get these warnings

```
TEST.c: In function ‘main’:
TEST.c:14:4: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘bst_inorder’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

In file included from TEST.c:3:0:
bst.h:10:13: note: expected ‘void (*)(char *)’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)(const char * __ restrict__)’
```

Comment: You might want to check the actual prototype of the [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) function. Which you of course have in the error message too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is simply because there really is a mis-match between your argument and the `printf()` function.

Your function expects `void (*)(char *)`, but `printf()`'s signature is `int (*)(const char *, ...)`. Clearly these are not the same.

It's probably OK, but the cleanest way to fix it is to write a "shim" or "trampoline" function:

```
static void print_node(char *str)
{
  printf("%s", str);
}
```

Then use that instead of `printf` directly in the call to `bst_inorder()`.

Not sure about the other problem, I think there's not enough code present to help with that.

Answer (score 2):

What it says - your function is expecting a function returning void, while `printf` returns int.

Other problem is that the correct syntax for pointer to function is like this:

```
void (*f)(char *str)
```

Or in case of `printf`:

```
int (*f)(const char *)
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning is clear, the 2nd argument of `bst_inorder` type mismatch.

I assume that you are trying to use `printf` to print strings only(i.e, not using the variable argument part), in that case, you can wrap it like this:

```
void my_printf(char *str)
{
    printf("%s", str);
}
```

And call it with:

```
bst_inorder(my_bst, my_printf);
```

Comment: Passing a message string to `printf` in place of a format string is a classic bug that usually leads to security breach.

Comment: @R.. Thanks, I didn't realize the potential problem, using `%s` is clearly a better choice.